# Problem with Synchronous motor

Tags: power, motor, vector-screen

I hope some one have an answer for me.

We have a 2600 HP synch motor driving two generators this feeds a mine winder typical ward leonard system.

The synch motor starts up through a korndorf starter and starts up normal. Currents balanced in the correct vector diagram. It reaches synch speed switches from star to run and then the excitation gets applied, the vector starts to go all over the place.

Typical VA and IA are correct but IB and IC flips to the other quadrant.  See attached picture. This effects the operation in running the Synch motor with DC excitation.

Have any one seen this before.

Why would this happen

At start up

[image: at start up]

After excitation applied

[image]

It is the first time I have seen something like this happen.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be slipping a pole? That can happen if the torque demand on the load side is greater than what the synchronous motor can deliver. You may want to check the generators or, assuming there is a double hafted gear box, check that for binding.

Also, are the generators immediately or already connected to the synchronous motor when the Korndorfer starter switches into full Run mode? If so, you may want to let the motor torque stabilize before doing so, and maybe stage them one after the other. Hopefully there is a clutch or something to allow the synchronous motor to get to speed before engaging the generators. If not, and it was working before, then go back to what I first said, look for a mechanical problem in the system.